# numpy.absolute returns negative numbers

Tags: python, numpy, absolute

I am using np.absolute to try to find datasets that have meaningful data. The data includes
negative numbers and I am trying to use the mean to decide wether it is meaningful. However, I don't want the negative values to cancel out the positive ones and give me a mean close to zero. Hence I use np.absolute, and take the mean of that. My code wasn't finding some datasets to be meaningful that I knew were, so I did some troublshooting, and found that np.absolute() was returning negative values! How can this be? Here is a shortened version of the program. I tested it and it has the same problem as the full version.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np


with h5py.File('<filename>.h5', 'r') as hdf:
    timestream_data = hdf.get('timestream')
    timestream = np.array(timestream_data)
    for x in timestream:
        timestream_list = timestream.tolist()
        dataset_as_list = x.tolist()
        print("Index: %d" % timestream_list.index(dataset_as_list), x, np.absolute(x))
```

And the output (I'll only include one of the lines that shows the error):
Index: 32 [ 127 -128 -128 ... -128 -128  127] [ 127 -128 -128 ... -128 -128  127]

Notice the last thing it should be printing on that line is np.absolute(x)... but there are negative values in the array...

Comment: This is almost certainly due to an overflow (due to an int8 array type used). Consider providing the type to Numpy (the automatic detection works well but it does not know what you will do on the array and the type semantics is not perfect either).

Comment: Note that `np.array([128], dtype=np.int8) == np.array([-128], dtype=np.int8)`

Comment: See [this active pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21648) for current work that will enable integer overflow such as this to generate a warning or an exception.

Comment: `127` is the max amount of a `int8`. After that, you get an overflow. You need to reserve more bits in memory to hold larger values, which is why we have `int16`, `in164`, `long` etc.